# Transpose matrix and inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

In one of the proofs in class there was given the equality for the dot product:

$$\langle Ax, Ax\rangle = \langle x, A^tAx\rangle$$

I don't understand why this is correct. Is there a way to show this without explicitly looking at the multiplications and sums?

thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is simpler than you might think.

By definition,
$$\langle x, y \rangle = x^{T}y\text{.}$$
Hence,
$$\langle Ax, Ax \rangle = (Ax)^{T}Ax$$
but by properties of matrix transposition, recall that 
$$(Ax)^{T}=x^{T}A^{T}$$
hence
$$\langle Ax, Ax \rangle = (Ax)^{T}Ax = x^{T}A^{T}Ax = (x)^{T}(A^TAx)=\langle x, A^TAx \rangle\text{.}$$

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer. Just for beginners like me: To be general, $\langle x,y \rangle = x^*y$ if it's a complex, where $x^*$ denotes a conjugate transpose.

Answer (score 3):

By definition

$$\langle Ax, Ax\rangle = x^TA^TAx= \langle x, A^TAx\rangle$$